# Why it cannot open this shared object in php?

Tags: php

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib64/php53/modules/mailparse.so' -
>   /usr/lib64/php53/modules/mailparse.so: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

How can we fix this this issue

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting this? When? What code is causing it?

Comment: I am getting this error on a SOAP library nusoap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use more appropriate permissions if the file exists, change the path if the file is somewhere else, re-install the mailparse extension with PECL if the file is not present.

But only if you're actually using mailparse - otherwise remove it from your php.ini

Comment: I am in shared hosting environment !

Comment: @phpqa.in contact your provider and tell them about the issue then. they are responsible to fix this issue by either installing the library correctly or removing it from the PHP configuration.